# How do I sync a networked folder with my dropbox folder?

Tags: sync, dropbox

I'm trying to sync a networked folder to dropbox:

- It is not an option to sync the files on the the computer that the files are created.
- The tool boxifier allows this type of functionality however this is not affordable.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do I Sync A networked folder with my  dropbox folder? @DavidPostill